# Woocommerce cart dwell time

Tags: web

I had an issue with woocommerce.

A user completed a purchase having the product in his cart after one year (Yes One Year), and bought at a different price, how is that possible?

I understand that Woocommerce limits the time to 48 hours. Any woocommerce expert who can guide me?